# Get corresponding model in laravel nova action fields function

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

How can I get the current model in the laravel nova actions field function? Can't find it out ...

```
public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
{
    Log::info($request->model());

    return [
        //
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I figured out was the solution to paste the model to the constructor of the action class:

```
public function actions(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return [
        (new Actions\MyAction($this))->onlyOnTableRow()
    ];
}
```

If this is really the best solution? Is there really no way to grab this from the NovaRequest?